# How to monitor if someone is using wireshark in my corporate network

Tags: network-monitoring, packet-sniffer

I would like to know if it's possible to monitor if any users are using a network sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) in my corporate network?.

Comment: This is answered there: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25011/how-can-i-detect-if-someone-is-sniffing-network-packets-on-the-lan

Comment: There are a number of IDS (Intrusion Detection System) products that will do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC Wireshark is copying data received by the network interface and working on them. I don't think it's possible to detect usage of Wireshark or other tools like tcpdump on network layer. On OS layer you might can check wether a device is entering promiscuous mode which indicates something is listening at the device.